# Coordinate representation of the tangent vector to a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Problem:

Given a smooth curve $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to M $, let $(U, \varphi)$ be a chart with $\gamma(I) \in U$ for some interval $I$. Write the coordinate representation for the tangent vector to $\gamma$,  $$(\varphi \circ \gamma)_{\ast}\dfrac{d}{dt}$$

---

I have that 
$$ (\varphi \circ \gamma)_{\ast} \dfrac{d}{dt} = \varphi_{\ast}\circ \gamma_{\ast}\dfrac{d}{dt}= \varphi_{\ast}\dfrac{d\gamma}{dt},$$ but I feel like this doesn't tell me very much. Am I going about this correctly?

Comment: Suppose you write $\varphi(\gamma(t)) = (x^1(t),\dots,x^n(t))$. Then what?

Comment: @TedShifrin I could write $(\varphi\circ\gamma(t))_{\ast}\dfrac{d}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt}(\varphi\circ\gamma(t)) = \dfrac{d}{dt}(x^1(t),\dots,x^n(t)) = (\dot{x}^1(t),\dots, \dot{x}^n(t))$

Comment: Right, and in the fancy manifolds notation this means that the tangent vector is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \dot x^i(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.$$